# what is the best practice to turn a python function to running in Apache Spark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a python program to deal with big data in one computer(16 cpu cores). Because the data is bigger and bigger, I need it to run in 5 computers. I am fresh in Spark,still feel Confused after read some docs. I will appreciate if anyone can tell me what is the best way to make a small cluster.

Here is some details:

1. The program is trying to count the trade volume in every price for each stock (one day for a time) from tick transaction pandas dataframe data.
2. There are more than 3000 stocks, 1 billion transactions in one day. The size of data file(dataframe) is between 1~2 G.
3. getting the result of 300 days spend for 3 days on one computer now, I hope to add 4 more computers to short the time.

here are the sample code in python:

```
import sharedmem
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

def ticks_to_priceline(day=None):

    # file name for the tick dataframe file, one day for a file
    fn = get_tick_dataframe_filename_byday(day)
    with pd.HDFStore(fn, 'r') as tick_store:
        tick_dataframe = tick_store.select("tick")
        all_stock_symbols = tick_dataframe.symbol.drop_duplicates()

        sblist = []
        # cut to small chunk
        chunk = 300
        for xx in range(len(all_stock_symbols) / chunk + 1):
            sblist.append(all_stock_symbols[xx * chunk:(xx + 1) * stuck])
        # run with all cpus
        with sharedmem.MapReduce(np=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:

            def work(chunk_list):
                result = {}
                for symbol in chunk_list:
                    data = tick_dataframe[tick_dataframe.symbol == symbol]
                    if not data.empty and len(data) > 99:
                        df1 = data.loc[:,
                                       [u'timestamp', u'price', u'volume']]
                        df1['vol_diff'] = df1.volume.diff().fillna(0)
                        df2 = df1.loc[:, ['price', 'vol_diff']]
                        df2.price = df2.price.apply(int)
                        rs = df2.groupby('price').sum()
                        rs = rs.sort_index(ascending=0).reset_index()

                        result[symbol] = rs
                return result

            rslist = pool.map(work, sblist)
    return rslist
```

here is a spark cluster in standalone mode I have already setup for testing. **My main problem is how to rewrite the codes above.**
[image]